# Create a link to a nested resource where the parent does not have resource name in the URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have setup my routes to work without the resource in the url (i.e. `/username/posts`, as opposed to `/users/username/posts`) - using friendly_id gem inorder to use `:username` instead of `:id`.

The resources are under a namespace (`cpanel`) and work fine.

My routes are setup like this:

```
namespace :cpanel do
  resources :users, :path => '', :constraints => { :id => /[\w+\-\_]+/ } do 
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

Navigating to `/cpanel/username/posts` works fine, but I am having trouble setting up my link_to I am using the path `cpanel_user_posts_path(@user)` but this creates a link to the URL `/cpanel/users/:username/apps`.

How can I create a link to the path: `/cpanel/:username/apps`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add your whole routes file or explain how "apps" gets included into the route?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

`get 'cpanel/:username/apps', to: 'controller#action`

You can always hard code it (as a last resort) via:

`link_to "Apps", "/#{current_user.username}/apps"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yeah hard coding works, but was hoping for a more 'dynamic' solution. May have to go down this road if I can't find a more elegant solution...

Comment: @8bithero you should be able to point a path at a controller action like did above. Did you try that?